# Why did Jasmine expect always return true in protractor (Web UI Automation Test)

Tags: angularjs, angular, jasmine, protractor, javascript-objects

I'm automating Web UI testing for an angular 2 website. However, I got a problem when wanting to check if the login step is successful. It always pass even I put the wrong password or the wrong XPath for logout button.

This element just exists when we login successfully. As i mentioned before, i intentionally put wrong password and even wrong xpath for btt_Logout (xbutton not button) so this element cannot exist but it's still true.

I don't understand what the problem is even I try a lot of things. I just change toBe(true) to toBe(false) but it still passes :). It seems to be that this expect does not work. I don't understand why

```
    import {browser, ExpectedConditions as EC, $, $$, element,by} from 'protractor'
    import { Login } from '../page_objects/login.page';
    import { helper } from '../helpers/helper'


    declare let expect:any;
    describe('Testing Login ', function () {
        beforeEach(async () => {

        })


        it('Go to loginpage', async function () {
//Go to Login Page
            Login.openHomePage();

        });
        it('Login to the page', async function () {
//Enter username, password and press OK. It work well.
            Login.login("admin","admin@123");
//Waiting to see btt_Logout. Problems in here. It always true even i make XPath of btt_Logout wrong or make password wrong. I check/
            browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(Login.btt_Logout), 30000).then(function () {
                expect((Login.btt_Logout).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            }, function (error) {
                expect(true).toBe(false);
            });

        });



        afterAll(()=> {

            helper.cleanUp();
            console.warn(`Test finished!`)
        })
    })
```

Login Page Object:

```
import {browser, ExpectedConditions as EC, $, $$, element, by, ElementFinder} from 'protractor'
import {BasePage} from './base.page'
require('../helpers/waitReady.js');

class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    //Internal element
    protected txt_LoginUsername: ElementFinder = element(by.id('username'));
    protected txt_LoginPassword: ElementFinder = element(by.id('password'));
    protected btt_LoginSubmit: ElementFinder = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-submit')]"));
    //External element

    public login(Username, Password) {
        this.txt_LoginUsername.sendKeys(Username);
        this.txt_LoginPassword.sendKeys(Password);
        this.btt_LoginSubmit.click();

    }
}

export const Login = new LoginPage();
```

Base Page:

```
import {browser, ExpectedConditions as EC, $, $$, element, by, ElementFinder} from 'protractor'
require('../helpers/waitReady.js');

export abstract class BasePage {
    protected url: string = '' // Will be same as baseUrl by default.
    public btt_Logout: ElementFinder = element(by.xpath("//xbutton[contains(@class,'btn-logout')]"));
    async openHomePage() {
        return await browser.get(this.url)
    }
    async openUrl(webUrl) {
        return await browser.get(webUrl)
    }
}
```

Result:
Started

JASMINE STARTING:

»  Testing Login 
        ▻  Go to loginpage
.       ✓  Go to loginpage (16 s)
        ▻  Login to the page
.       ✓  Login to the page (0.234 s)
Test finished!

2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 16.599 seconds

---

- Summary                     *

  ---

Executed 2 out of 2 specs in 17 s

```
    PASSED   2 ( 100% )
    FAILED   0 ( 0% )
    SKIPPED  0 ( 0% )
```

[22:38:58] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[22:38:58] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that my issue is that I put the element login_button in base_page and it makes a big issue. When protractor opens, it will be looking for this element and it causes we must wait for a long time. – Mike just now   edit

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're using `isPresent()` in `expect((Login.btt_Logout).isPresent()).toBe(true);` which checks if the element exists so it returns true.

Comment: But why it's always true. As I mentioned before, I put the wrong password and wrong XPath for btt_Logout but it's still true.

Comment: Because the element always exists thus it is always present and in return is always true.

Comment: No, this element just exists when we login successfully. As i mentioned before, i intentionally put wrong password and even wrong xpath for btt_Logout (xbutton) so this element cannot exist but it's still true.

Answer (score 0):

Your expect isn't getting triggered, not to mention the wait clutters up your test. Also, `presenceOf` only checks the element is in the dom, not it's visibility.

Try throwing the wait in your `login()` method (which is probably the right place for it anyway), and making the logout button public. Protractor/jasmine will handle the wait for you in the `expect`.

```
import {browser, ExpectedConditions as EC, $, $$, element, by, ElementFinder} from 'protractor'
import {BasePage} from './base.page'
require('../helpers/waitReady.js');

class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    //Internal element
    protected txt_LoginUsername: ElementFinder = element(by.id('username'));
    protected txt_LoginPassword: ElementFinder = element(by.id('password'));
    protected btt_LoginSubmit: ElementFinder = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-submit')]"));
    public btt_Logout: ElementFinder = element(by.xpath("//xbutton[contains(@class,'btn-logout')]"));
    //External element

    public login(Username, Password) {
        this.txt_LoginUsername.sendKeys(Username);
        this.txt_LoginPassword.sendKeys(Password);
        this.btt_LoginSubmit.click();
        return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.btt_Logout), 30000, 'timeout: waiting for login');
    }
}

export const Login = new LoginPage();
```

Then your test would be...

```
    it('Login to the page', async function () {
        Login.login("admin","admin@123");

        expect(Login.btt_Logout.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Brine, i changed to isVisible but it still does not work. This element just exists when we login successfully. As i mentioned before, i intentionally put wrong password and even wrong xpath for btt_Logout (xbutton) so this element cannot exist but it's still true.

Comment: I just change toBe(true) to toBe(false) but it still passes :). It seems to be that this function does not work.

Comment: woops, I meant `isDisplayed()`. Which means your `expect` definitely isn't getting triggered.

Comment: yes, my expect is not be triggered. But actually, I don't know why.

Comment: I updated my answer. Something with your wait is skipping the expect. This should either work, or hopefully give you a clue to the issue.

Comment: Hi, it still does not work. However, when i set the         browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000) (before that I never set this timeout) and set a timeout of browser.wait<5000. It seems to trigger the expect.

Comment: Hi Brine,
Do I have some mistake when declaring the page object like that. When i set the implicitlyWait(20000) it take so long time to enter the username and password.... As I know implicitlyWait just the timeout until the element appear

Comment: I just found that my issue is that I put the element login_button in base_page and it makes a big issue. When protractor opens, it will be looking for this element and it causes we must wait for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if that certain object is not present in the HTML/CSS?

There are cases where in if you are checking a TEXT,
the element might still be there and only displays EMPTY value,
that's why it does not look visible but isPresent and isDisplayed.